# /etc/profile: Permission denied after restarting Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, file-permissions, amazon-ec2

I restarted my Amazon EC2 instance and all of sudden when I log in from SSH via putty I get the error:

```
-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
-bash: /etc/bashrc: Permission denied
```

Previously I was able to log in via SSH but after restart I can not.
I do have access to Super User so I can change permissions.
I tried changing permissions on `/etc/profile` like 770 and 771 but couldn’t fix the issue.

Permissions on both files is `750`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my EC2 instance, the permissions on `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile` are `0665`. You should change your install to use those permissions and restart the server to have the changes take affect.

Answer (score -2):

they should be 700 and 600 respectively

Comment: why 700 and 600?

Comment: Its not the rc or profile files themselves that are the issue its that they don't have access to the ssh key  which itself should be  600 in a parent folder  toting a 700

Comment: true, but those two files mentioned above have `0665` as the permission

Comment: why would you need ANY OTHER user but the user in question to have r/w or write /execute on YOUR file

Comment: it's not `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` these are `0665` on `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: which are read prior to ~/bashrc & ~/profile   and I highly doubt a  global access strategy to those files is desired either

Comment: did not fix the error

Comment: I'm just putting the exact output or ls -l /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc